# Detect if browser has more then 1 tab/window open

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs, sandbox

So i am developing a quiz web application. And i wanted to add a setting that the administrator of the quiz could set that would make it so the user could only have 1 window/tab open while the quiz is being taken.

The reason for this is to make it so they cant goto like google and google the answer while the quiz window/tab is open. Of course they could always open a different browser and do it that way, but still thought it would be a nice feature to have for them to enable.

Now i dont know if this would fall under a security sandbox violation (and thus not be available at all) but since i only want to detect if another tab or window is open and not get actual information about the tab/window i am hoping that this is someway possible using javascript.

Comment: You can't do it, and thank heavens for that fact.

Comment: Because your users would have only one browser installed, or be unable to run separate instances of the one browser..? I second Pointy, thank goodness this can't be done.

Comment: No you can't do, but you can use Jquery (Ajaxed) UI tabs - this is exactly what want.

Comment: @metal_fan: How would that help? He wants to 1) *prevent* any tab from being opened, and 2) prevent tabs at the browser level.

Comment: @metal_fan that is not even close to what he wants...

Comment: just make sure that the answer cannot be googled :)

Comment: @pimvdb of course he should implement his own model of handling the data from server. Then should allow / prevent the tabs from being opened from JSON respond he got.

Comment: @metal_fan: Not sure if we're on the same wavelength. It's nothing to do with JSON as I understand it. Preventing jQuery UI tabs isn't a solution at all - it doesn't quite make sense implementing it at all here, I guess.

Comment: I am not trying to prevent tabs or windows from being opened, i am saying that if the user starts a quiz, the javascript would check if there are other windows/tabs are open and tell the user that it will not start the quiz till all other tabs windows are closed. And if the user opens a tab or window while the quiz is on going that it will stop the quiz or some other preventive measure of letting the user continue with the quiz. Also @akonsu i will not be making the actual questions the administrator of the quiz application will enter their own questions/answers etc

Comment: You want me to close all my other tabs and windows to take a quiz on your site? Must be a a really great quiz..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, but a possible workaround would be to use the new [HTML5 fullscreen API](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/).  You could use a `setInterval` function to regularly test that `document.fullScreen == true` to ensure that the user has not toggled off the full screen.

This only works in modern browsers, and it's trivial to work around if the user knows his way around the JS console, but it does seem to fit your requirements.

Note that all fullscreen API implementations are currently [vendor-prefixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be viable alternative to the approach described below the line: using [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), currently supported by all the modern browsers. This looks like far more reliable than listening for `blur`. There's one possible way to do it:

```
// on quiz start
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log('Y U hide?');
  }
});
```

The problem is that `visibilitychange` event is fired only when page goes from visible to hidden (and vise versa). It still lets user open two browser instances - one with the quiz page, one with *any favorite search engine*, for example.

---

While you cannot detect the number of tabs open, you can try to check when the user goes away from the quiz page with this trick:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).blur(function() {
    console.log('I see what you did here!');
  });
});
```

Sadly, it'll also give you plenty of false positives.

Comment: Missing closing parenthese for $(window).blur(function()

Answer (score 3):

Can't, and shouldn't, be done.

Comment: Why shouldn't? As all i want is a detection if other windows tabs are open, not a preventor of them being open just a check if there are others open. I do not see how that is a security risk or any other kind of risk for that matter.

Comment: If it's not a security issue then I'd imagine it's just that some people think that the ability to cheat on online tests is a human right or something.