# Can it be determined if window.resizeTo will work?

Tags: javascript

Inside the Javascript console, if I execute:

```
m = window.open(location.origin);
m.resizeTo(400, 400);
```

The window will resize, but if I just execute:

```
window.resizeTo(400, 400);
```

then nothing happens. I understand the reason for this behavior. How can I detect situations where window.resizeTo will do nothing?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to check the window height, resize it by a pixel, and check it again.

Comment: @Zirak That's a very user hostile idea.

Comment: Resizing a window by *a pixel* and then resizing it back, probably faster than they can notice?

Comment: @Zirak solution is the answer you are looking for. if you change window's size by a pixel, save the size and immediately revert, user wouldn't notice the resize, because it never actually happened (window's size is applied asynchronously)

Comment: in fact if you open a popup that is 500x500 and launch: window.resizeTo(300,300); window.resizeTo(500,500); you won't see the window moving at all (even if the onresize event is still triggered)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach 1:

You can use the `window.opener` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener).  If it's null, then you did not open that window and thus cannot resize it.

`window.parent` is [intended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.parent) more for `iframes` and the like.

Such as:

```
if (m.opener) {
    m.resizeTo(400, 400);
} else {
    // You did not create the window, and will not be able to resize it.
}
```

### Approach 2:

ajp15243 brings up a good point, so one thing you could do is listen to the resize event and see if your `resizeTo` worked:

```
var resizeFired = false;
...
var triggeredResize = function() {
    resizeFired = true;

    m.removeEventListener('resize', triggeredResize);
}

m.addEventListener('resize', triggeredResize, true);

m.resizeTo(400, 400);

if (resizeFired) {
    // Your resize worked.
}
```

I haven't been able to fully test this, but it's one potential approach nonetheless.  For IE8 and below you may need to use `attachEvent` instead.  Also as @Wesabi noted, the resize may fire for other events (and may fire if the user is resizing the window as the listener as attached), so it's best to execute this is the shortest time span possible.

### Approach 3:

Another approach would be to call `m.resizeTo(400, 400)` and then check the window size to see if the current size is equal to what you set it to:

```
m.resizeTo(400, 400);
if (w.outerWidth != 400 && w.outerHeight != 400) {
   // Your resize didn't work
}
```

Comment: This would seem to cover the first rule in the `window.resizeTo` docs, but the second rule about multiple tabs [doesn't seem to be possible to detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404538/detect-if-browser-has-more-then-1-tab-window-open).

Comment: @ajp15243 Good point, I've posted an alternate approach as well.

Comment: also note that the resize event on msie8 and below fires on any element (not only window)

Comment: @Wesabi Yeah, it also doesn't account for user resize.  My assumption is that the logic shoudl happen in a short enough timespan that it shouldn't matter.  But yeah, that's definitely another consideration.  This is more of a hack.  "Ideally" we want `resizeTo` to return a Boolean on its success state.

Comment: solution is fine! but i think OP wanted to check in advance if resize will work, but sadly this is impossible... i'd go with zirak's solution  suggested in the comments, it's the less invasive one

Comment: (for approach 3 it's actually outerWidth and outerHeight, that sadly aren't crossbrowser)

Comment: @Wesabi D'oh, that's what I get for not testing it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be checking if the window has a `parent`. if `!window.parent`, it means it's the main window which cannot be resized with JS, else you have your resize case.

Edit: Igor posted it before I found it: you want `m.opener()` not `window.parent`

Comment: Note that this using this method will have undesired results if your page is embedded as an iframe.

Comment: If I execute `[!window.parent, !m.parent]` I get `[false, false]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The top `window` for me has a self-reference for `window.parent`, so wouldn't `!window.parent` always be `false`? Wouldn't you want `window !== window.parent` instead to check if it's not the top-level window?

Comment: Ah, I found it after Igor posted his asnwer. I wanted `m.opener()`

Answer (score 0):

MDN is a great JavaScript resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeTo

> Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a  window in a browser, according to the following rules:
>
> **You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open**.
>
> You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

SO, you need to detect if you are a child window:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener

```
if (window.opener) { 
  console.log('I can be resized'); 
} else { 
    console.log('I cannot be resized'); 
}
```

Comment: My question was if this situation can be detected, as I said, I understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Yes, the question precisely was about how such situations can be detected. The fact that it cant be done was stated as known.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious. Since you cannot resize a window that wasn't created by window.open, you must detect this condition. The answer has been updated to demonstrate how you would do this.